# Why does WebSockets only work with websocket.org

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket

Why does WebSockets only work with websocket.org and not through localhost? All I get is undefined from javascript. What's so special  about `ws://websocket.org`?

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/includes/php/UnitTest/WebSocketTest.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

I have tried all port numbers `ws://localhost:80/` same problem

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80/includes/php/UnitTest/WebSocketTest.php");
    ws.onopen = function() { alert("open");}
    ws.onerror = function(e){alert(e.reason+ " " + e.code);}

</script>
```

I am reading two books **The Definitive Guide to HTML5 WebSocket** and **O'Reilly WebSocket** and none of them talk or point out this problem, I thought this was all standard stuff by now?

Can you help?

Comment: This is probably because you are not handling websockets properly in your PHP code. The HTTP 200 means that the page is returning like a normal web page,rather than return HTTP 101 to switch to websocket. Show the code you are using for handling the connection.

Comment: appreciate the response

it was just 

<?php
echo "test";
?>


am thinking its like XHR where you can post stuff to php $_POST['stuff'] from javascript
omg now am getting 

"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8181/includes/php/UnitTest/WebSocketTest.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

what am i missing?

Comment: You are missing the whole websocket thing :D. XHR is just the capability of JS to make HTTP requests. WebSockets is a different communication mechanism, although it starts as a HTTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side must be ready to accept WebSocket connections.

In PHP you can use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) for this. You can find a basic tutorial here: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world